# strange implicit conversion on C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have a question about an unexpected conversion:

```
class BadString
{
 public:
    BadString(char const*);
    ...
    char& operator[] (size_t);            //(1)
    char const& operator[] (size_t);

    operator char* ();                    //(2)
    operator char const* ();
```

};

```
int main()
{
    BadString str("correkt");
    str[5] = 'c';  //possibly an overload resolution ambiguity !!!
}
```

The explanation goes like this:

> The subscript operator at (1) seems like a perfect match. However is not quite perfect because the argument 5 has type int, and the operator expects size_t (unsigned int or unsigned long, but never int). Still, a simple standard integer conversion makes (1) easily viable.
>   However, there is another candidate: the built-in subscript operator. Indeed, if we apply the conversion operator (2) to str, we obtain a pointer type, and now the the built-in subscript operator applies. This operator takes a ptrdiff_t argument, which on many platforms is equivalent to int.

I understand that the original parameters for (1) was not matched, and then an implicit conversion will take place, but I don't understand why the compiler will try to convert str, using (2).

Thank you.

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile: you are overloading `operator[]` by return type.

Comment: You need to make the function `char const& operator[] (size_t)` constant, e.g. `char const& operator[] (size_t) const;`

Comment: It's good form to indicate the source when you're quoting things.

Comment: Have implicit `operator char *` is a bad idea anyway

Comment: "C++ Templates, the complete guide", VanDeVoorde & Josuttis: B.2.1 The Implied Argument for Member Functions

Comment: Having both `operator[]` and a pointer conversion operator is even more of a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I 'expand' your code like this and make second subscript operator method const, so the result will be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class BadString {
  public:
      char s[1024];
      BadString(const char* s_)  {
          strncpy(s, s_, strlen(s_) + 1);
      }
      char& operator[](size_t pos) {
          return s[pos];
      }
      const char& operator[](size_t pos) const {
          return s[pos];
      }

      operator char*() {
          std::cout << "operator char*\n";
      }

      operator const char*() {
          std::cout << "operator const char*\n";
      }
};

int main() {
    BadString bs("correkt");
    bs[5] = 'c';
    std::cout << bs.s << "\n";
}
```

then compile it and run, it works as expected, output is just one line

```
correct
```

Such fact as `(2)` implicit conversion operator takes place means you did not provide full information about `BadString` class. Maybe you should do so.

And, of course, if it is implemented like in provided example, there is no any reason to
call `(2)` implicit conversion operator.

**UPD:** Thinking about what you mentioned in comment, I suppose the purpose of 
`operator const char*()` was that  **explicit** conversion like

```
(const char*)bs
```

returned pointer to first element of an array `s`, that `bs` is holding. That is, of course,
incorrect, and a bit ugly, but there is the only option that I see.

Comment: I think on the book, the intention of implementing operator const char*() was returning the equivalent of s[0], in your example. I complete see why your example doesn't have overload resolution issues.

Comment: `s[0]` will call non-const `bs.operator[](0)`, which will return a reference to `s[0]` which, by 'definition', is `*s` and has type `char`. I cannot understand, what conversion will take place?

Comment: "if we apply the conversion operator (2) to str, we obtain a pointer type,..."

Comment: That's exactly what I meant in UPD in answer. It is explicit conversion.